# Rate of evaporation of mercury

Tags: experimental-chemistry, vapor-pressure

A restorer of antique barometers [reported in a blog post](http://www.charlesedwin.com/mercury.htm) that he has had a barometer on his wall that has shown no "visible" loss of mercury in 15 years.

I was kind of curious about this, wondering how long it would be before a barometer would evaporate completely. How can I compute the rate of evaporation from the vapor pressure?

For the barometer reading to become inaccurate, the well would have to evaporate completely until the 0 point was reached (at highest pressure), then it would start becoming inaccurate.

Comment: [This](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1568971) abstract alone doesn't quite answer your question, but the full paper probably would come close if you had access. They found a "small" droplet of Hg evaporated in an open container at 1.6 ug/hr and a "large" drop at 6.0 ug/hr. There is no definition of small or large droplet size, though they do describe the container. If you had the full article I guess you would have to try to calculate diffusion rates through the barometer. It would be an interesting article, though I don't have access beyond the abstract.